How to convert the data of speed versus time of electric vehicle to the data of battery current versus time？
the Urban Dynamometer Driving Schedule (UDDS) is a specific driving condition of electric vehicle, which is composed of a series of data of speed versus time. in this link,
https://github.com/zshaoxin2016/UDDS_current, the udds.txt is the original data of UDDS and the udds_current.txt, which is converted from the udds.txt, is the data of battery current versus time for a specific lithium-ion battery, whose parameter settings are shown in a picture, battery parameters.PNG. I want to know how to convert the udds.txt into the corresponding udds_current.

This question is well beyond the bounds of this group.  The answer is going to depend on the construction of the entire car -- the mechanics, the motors, the electronics, the control algorithms, the batteries, probably the aerodynamics, and goodness knows what else.  Modeling this from a car design could take man-years if you wanted good accuracy; measuring it would mean popping the car on a dynamometer and getting your numbers.  I suggest migrating this question to engineering.stackexchange.com: when you do, clarify what you know about the car and how much accuracy you need.

Not to mention external factors like wind speed, load and uphill vs downhill, acceleration and breaking — and even with an estimation of the acceleration from the current and then velocity from that would result in a random walk error term that would quickly drift from any prediction of velocity or position. However the battery current could perhaps be good input to a Kalman steered estimate of those parameters combined with other sensors (which would then be the application where such use of battery current could be very interesting).

Thank you very much for your comments
